# SQL Server : copy a row from the inserted table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have 2 tables in SQL Server. The first one is `Grades`, the second one is `Tokens`.

`Grades` has following columns:

```
Token, SubjectID, SubjectName, ...
```

Dots represent a number of columns. This is the dynamic table, so it might look like this:

```
Token, SubjectID, SubjectName, LAB_grade, LECTURE_grade
```

and after f.e. 1 minute, it can look like this:

```
Token, SubjectID, SubjectName, LAB_grade, LECTURE_grade, TEST_grade, SEM_grade
```

The `Tokens` table is as follows:

```
access_token, access_token_secret, user_login, Notifications, phone_number, email
```

Where `Notifications` are `0`,`1`,`2` or `3` where

- `0` means, do nothing
- `1` means, send an email notification,
- `2` send an sms notification,
- `3` send both notifications

In order to do this I've created a simple trigger and procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE send_email
      (@email nvarchar(100), @access_token nvarchar(200), @newRow nvarchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'EMAIL:' + @email + ', TOKEN: ' + @access_token + ', NEW ROW: ' + @newRow
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE send_email_sms
     (@phone nvarchar(20), @email nvarchar(100), @access_token nvarchar(200), @newRow nvarchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT '(send_email_sms) PHONE_NR: ' + @phone+ ', EMAIL:' + @email + ', TOKEN: ' + @access_token + ', NEW ROW: ' + @newRow
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE send_sms
    (@phone nvarchar(20), @email nvarchar(100), @access_token nvarchar(200), @newRow nvarchar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT '(send_sms) PHONE_NR: ' + @phone + ', EMAIL:' + @email + ', TOKEN: ' + @access_token + ', NEW ROW: ' + @newRow
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER insertToGrades ON Grades
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newRow nvarchar(500)

    SET @newRow = (SELECT * FROM inserted)

    DECLARE @access_token nvarchar(200)
    SET @access_token = (SELECT Token FROM inserted)

    DECLARE @type_of_notification nvarchar(2)
    SET @type_of_notification = (SELECT Notifications FROM Tokens WHERE access_token = @access_token)

    DECLARE @phone nvarchar(20)
    SET @phone = (SELECT phone_number FROM Tokens WHERE access_token = @access_token)

    DECLARE @email nvarchar(100)
    SET @email = (SELECT email FROM Tokens WHERE access_token = @access_token)

    IF(@type_of_notification = 0)
        return

    IF(@type_of_notification = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.send_email @email, @access_token, @newRow
    END

    IF(@type_of_notification = 2)
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.send_sms @phone, @email, @access_token, @newRow
    END

    IF(@type_of_notification = 3)
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.send_email_sms @phone, @email, @access_token, @newRow
    END
END
```

There is a problem with this line:

```
SET @newRow = (SELECT * FROM inserted)
```

because:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is it possible for me to get a row that is in `inserted` table and put it to a variable like f.e. `@newRow` (in order to pass it to the appropriate procedure) ? I can't use syntax that refers to a particular column name, because columns in the `Grades` table are dynamic

Comment: Are you really adding and dropping columns from a table?  As far as getting the record, the trigger has to be aware of not just one, but multiple records being updated.  You can either say (SELECT TOP 1...) which is probably a bad idea or you can take the output and insert it into another table OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO @MyTableVar

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: It sounds like you ought to be normalizing your design. Rather than tacking a column on to `Grades` each time a gradable entity is instantiated (?!) you should create additional tables that you can join, e.g. `ClassEvents` (`ClassId`, `ClassEventId`, `EventName`) and `StudentGradesForEvents` (`StudentId`, `ClassEventId`, `Grade`). You can keep adding rows to `ClassEvents` for each quiz, exam, paper, lab, project, ... required for each class. The students grades get recorded in `StudentGradesForEvents`. That way the schema remains stable. Don't forget to allow for students repeating classes!

Comment: If you could slide an entire row from a table into an `nvarchar`, what do you think it would look like? How would you retrieve columns from it? Could you use it to do a row insert elsewhere? Have you looked into the [`xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) data type?